# How to display Jupyter Notebook connection info while everything else sent to a log file?

Tags: background-process, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am writing a developer tool, part of which will launch a Jupyter notebook in the background with output sent to a particular file, such as

```
jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root \
  >> ${NOTEBOOK_LOGFILE} 2>&1 &
```

However, I still want the notebook's start-up information to be printed to the console via stdout. Such as

```
[I 18:25:33.166 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 18:25:33.189 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /faces
[I 18:25:33.189 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 18:25:33.189 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://0.0.0.0:8888/?token=b02f25972...
[I 18:25:33.189 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 18:25:33.189 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://0.0.0.0:8888/?token=b02f25972...
```

so that users can still see which URL connection string they need.

I have tried to `cat` this file after the notebook command but this has some downsides.

The time it takes for the notebook to launch and print the message is variable, and using a combination of `sleep` along with `cat` the log file is undesirable, because if there's a rare delay in start-up time, `cat` of the log file might print nothing because the file is empty.

On the other hand, I don't want to set the sleep time to an overly high number, because then users will have to wait too long at startup.

I have also tried `tail -f ${NOTEBOOK_LOGFILE} | grep -n 10` (because the start-up lines will be the first 10). This is promising, but the notebook server does not append a newline to each line until the next line is incoming. This means if you wait for 10 lines, the `tail` process will hang until some other message is logged to the log file (producing the 10th newline).

How can I ensure that the start-up information is displayed to stdout in a timely fashion from when the notebook outputs this information, while still redirecting notebook output into a log file?

Answer (score 0):

I figured a hack to do it with `tail` and `head`, but would be interested in something simpler.

```
(tail -f -n +1 ${NOTEBOOK_LOGFILE} | head -n 5);
```

This relies on the fact that the connection URL is also printed among the first 5 lines, and so it won't matter about the lack of newline that keeps `head` waiting if you try to extract it from lines 9 and 10.